# C - Add an element to a struct pointer

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

Im trying to add a a struct Song to my struct pointer song* but when trying to write it to a file it just gives out junk.
This is my function:

```
void addSong(Song *song, char songName[], char artistName[], int publicationYear, int *nrOfSongs)
{
    Song *tempSongs = (Song*)malloc(sizeof(Song)*(*nrOfSongs));

    for (int i = 0; i < (*nrOfSongs); i++)
        {
            strcpy(tempSongs[i].artistName, song[i].artistName);
            strcpy(tempSongs[i].songName, song[i].songName);
            tempSongs[i].publicationYear = song[i].publicationYear;
        }

    free(song);
    *nrOfSongs = (*nrOfSongs) + 1;
    song = (Song*)malloc(sizeof(Song)*(*nrOfSongs));


    for (int i = 0; i < ((*nrOfSongs)-1); i++)
        {
            strcpy(song[i].artistName, tempSongs[i].artistName);
            strcpy(song[i].songName, tempSongs[i].songName);
            song[i].publicationYear = tempSongs[i].publicationYear;
        }
}
```

Edit 1: Sorry for the bad question.

My function writeToFile:

```
void writeToFile(char fileName[], Song *song, int *nrOfSongs)
{
    char name[256];
    snprintf(name, sizeof(name), "%s.txt", fileName);
    FILE * file = fopen(name, "w");

    fprintf(file, "%d", *nrOfSongs);
    fputc('\n', file);

    for (int i = 0; i < (*nrOfSongs); i++)
    {
        fputs(song[i].songName, file);
        fputs(song[i].artistName, file);
        fprintf(file, "%d", song[i].publicationYear);
        fputc('\n', file);
    }

    fclose(file);
}
```

An example of a file:

```
4
Mr Tambourine Man
Bob Dylan
1965
Dead Ringer for Love
Meat Loaf
1981
Euphoria
Loreen
2012
Love Me Now
John Legend
2016
```

I want to add a song and by that i want to add an artistName, songName and publicationYear to my struct pointer and then write the struct pointer to a new file.

Comment: There is no reason for this function to return void. Just return a pointer to the allocated structs instead.

Comment: Most of the important part is missing. You do not show anything about writing to a file. How do you call your function? How do you write to a file? What do you expect to be written? What is in the file? How do you check what was written?

Comment: Needs more [mcve].

Comment: What more can be added?? There is honstly not much more i can add of relevance here...

Comment: @AntonLindstrand At minimum, a `main` function. It won't even compile otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of copying over arrays twice, you should enlarge the array `song` using `realloc()`, and just add the new element to it, like so:

```
Song *addSong(Song *song, char songName[], char artistName[], int publicationYear, int *nrOfSongs) {
  *nrOfSongs++;
  song = realloc(song, *nrOfSongs * sizeof *song);
  // Don't forget to do error checking here, realloc() may return NULL

  strcpy(song[*nrOfSongs - 1].artistName, artistName);
  // et cetera

  return song;
}
```

Because you are reallocating the memory, the pointer to the array changes, so you have to return the new pointer to the caller, like @wildplasser says.

Also, `strcpy()` is an unsafe function. Consider using a safer alternative, like `snprintf()`.

Comment: Note `strncpy()` is a terrible function, and certainly not usable here.

Comment: Well yes, it `strncpy()` has its own problems. I updated the text to suggest `snprintf()`, which is a bit overkill. `strlcpy()` or `strcpy_s()` might also be options, if your platform supports those.